# 2010 Recent sub Site Wiki Page Changes Rollup with Content Query webpart

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part, wiki

I have a my SharePoint 2010 enterprise implementation.

I am trying to implement a Webpart in a site that shows all the latest changes from a sub site wiki libraries. Unfortunately the result set is blank.

This was inspired by video I saw by Mike Gannotti on Enterprise Knowledge Management.

http://socialmedia.mikegannotti.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=770fd871-67e5-4d2c-b71f-586f7900cf8a&ID=495

- Main_Site called "plm"  (Which in turn is a subsite of a site "project")

  - Site Page "Home" with Content Query webpart
    *SubSite called "FAQ"
  - Libraries
  - Wiki Library One called "Word FAQ"

    - Wiki Page one "Home"
    - Wiki Page two "How To Use This Library"
  - Wiki Library Two called "Excel FAQ"

    - Wiki Page three "Home"
    - Wiki Page four "How To Use This Library"

Process used to create Sub Wiki Site is:

1. In Main site create a site based on "Blank Site" template, called "FAQ"
2. Add the "FAQ" site to the Sites Global Navigation
3. In the FAQ site add two libraries based on Wiki Page Libraries called "Word FAQ" and "Excel FAQ"
4. On Site Page "Home" home add Content Query webpart with the following settings

```
Content Query Tool Part 
Query
Source:
* Show items from the following site and all subsites: /Projects/plm/FAQ
List Type:#
Show items from this list type:
Wiki Page Library
Show items of this content type:
Wiki Page
Grouping and Sorting:
Sort items by:
Modified
Descending order
```

Leave all other settings as default

Unfortunately the result is a column of (blank)'s.

Any suggestions? Should this work, ......

Comment: Having the same issue here. A Wiki Page Library that is attached as the query for the content query webpart provides a title but, also provides a whole slew of (blank) items that can be clicked on. Once clicked they resolve at:

https://yourdomainhere.com/_layouts/CopyUtil.aspx?Use=id&Action=dispform&ItemId=19&ListId=d2b3e367-a31b-42aa-a07c-1b1eccaddd46&WebId=f03f543d-afcf-49b7-89f0-c1c3a4ca4803&SiteId=27658fe3-ccee-43ca-96f1-20b9f102feeb&Source=https%3A%2F%2Fyourdomainhere%2Ecom%2FSitePages%2FHome%2Easpx

Anyone figure this out yet?